# Real time navigation with map services

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bing-maps

I want to develop an application that uses **google map** or **bing map** to
show users their current location and navigate them to another location.

I want that the map update in real time when user moving showing the tracking path.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Google Maps API v3 should work... you just have to poll the users GPS every 10 seconds or so, and update the map location.

Comment: @tony.gustafsson, can you give me some example to start with?

Answer (score 0):

The terms of use of both Google Maps and Bing Maps restrict the use of their maps in real time navigation type scenarios.

In the Google Maps terms of use, see section 2(i): http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/help/terms_maps.html

In the Bing Maps terms of use, see section 3.2(e): https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html